# Can you change the name of an app after its been submitted to the app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I'm 99.9% certain this isn't possible, but just want to double check and confirm.
If you make a submission to the app store, then after making the submission the customer / Product Marketing department decide they want to change the name, is this possible without making another submission to the app store?

Note - two parts to the question, there's the app name as it appears on the device (this won't be possible to change if the bundle is read only), but what about just changing the name of the app on the app store? I'm sure I read this isn't possible in the app guidelines but I can't find that quote right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only change an app's name between adding a new version in iTunes Connect and submitting the binary for the new version.

Go to Itunes Connect. Click on the FAQ link, then on "Manage Your Apps". That is the page with info about renaming your app.

> **How can I edit my app name?**
>   App names can only be changed when your app is in an editable state. Changing the app name on iTunes Connect will only change the app name on the App Store. If you need to change the app name that displays on a customer’s device, you need to edit this name in the binary of your app and send a binary update.
>
> Note that you must also change the app name for each of your localizations.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm, for some reason my Apple id is generating "does not have permission to access iTunes connect" so I can't access the faqs. What constitutes and editable state, and if the binary is resubmitted then does the whole approval process re-start?

Comment: The 1st sentence of my answer covers the editable state. I should add that if a binary is rejected, you go back to an editable state until the next binary is uploaded. And yes, submitting a new binary puts you back at the end of the queue.

Comment: I also faced the same situation, but in XCode 5 once you change the app name the Bundle ID will change too, doesn't it affect the link to the application? or make any problem or conflict? because I advertise for my app using the link that is similar to the bundle ID...